# I have java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: java

```
package RMI_Package;

import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class MyRemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote {
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Server says,'Hey'";
    }

    public MyRemoteImpl() throws RemoteException{}

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
            Naming.rebind("Remote Hello",service);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> This code is from Head First Java Book when i run it, it throws the java.net.MalformedURLException.

Comment: You get that Exception because "Remote Hello" is a malformed URL.

Comment: and how i can fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

As specified by [the `Naming` documentation](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java7/java/rmi/Naming.html#bind(java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote)), the first parameter of `bind` should be a valid URL.

As an example (taken from [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=java.rmi.Naming)):

```java
Naming.bind("rmi://localhost:8800/YourObject", service);
```